# AngularJS : Returning .then() response to controller property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I'm using a factory to retrieve data using `$http` and the `controllerAs` capabilities to inject into my view. Without the use of the `$scope`, I am having issues returning the `$http` response data into a property in my controller.

**My Factory**

```
myApp.factory('Topics', function ($http, $q) {
    var service = {},
        _error = 'Oh no! Something went wrong. Please check back later.';


    service.getTopics = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get(_url).success(function (resp) {
            deferred.resolve(resp);
        }).error (function () {
            deferred.reject(_error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return service;
});
```

**My Controller**

```
 myApp.controller('TopicsCtrl', function (Topics) {
    this.topics = (function () {
        return Topics.getTopics().then(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            return resp;
        });
    })();
}
```

**My View**

```
<h1>{{ top.topics }}</h1>
```

Like I said I'm using `controllerAs` in my route which is configured to `top`. The `console.log` in the controller logs what I'm looking for but the value of `topics` is empty when it is injected into the view. Leaving me with {}.

P.S. From what I understand `$http` is an abstraction of `$q` which makes me wonder if using `$q` in this example is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
  myApp.controller('TopicsCtrl', function (Topics) {
    Topics.getTopics().then(function (resp) {
      this.topics = resp;
    }.bind(this));
  });
```

Then access it in your view via top.topics.

Edit: Also, you're correct in not needing $q in your service. You can just return the $http.get directly:

```
service.getTopics = function() {
    return $http.get(_url);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did was to initialize top.topics with a promise. But angular views can't do anything with promises. What they need is the actual data, accessible when the promise is resolved. So what you need is:

```
// oh the joys of this...
var that = this;

Topics.getTopics().then(function (resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    that.topics = resp;
});
```

Note that you could use promise chaining in the service:

```
    return $http.get(_url).then(function (resp) {
        return resp.data;
    }).catch(function() {
        return $q.reject(_error);
    });
```